# FASTMM Debug Version with C++ Builder 10.x

Tags: c++, c++builder

Has anyone ever gotten FastMM4BCB.cpp to compile and work successfully with C++ Builder 10.1 or later?

I am using 10.2.3 and I keep getting the following error when I try and compile it in my application:

[C++ Error] typeinfo.h(154, 2): E2367 Can't inherit RTTI class from non-RTTI base 'exception'

It has been this way for YEARS and I can't seem to find a fix. I am trying to track down a memory leak issue.

Comment: Your question assumes everyone knows what `FastMM4BCB.cpp` is. I doubt that. What is it? Where did you find it? What is the actual content in the file at/around the reported line?

Comment: If you are about this [repo](https://github.com/gabr42/FastMM4-MP) (first thing that came up when googling the provided filename, it hasn't been updated since 2016, so I don't thing anything even could have changed.